# Notification Service - System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

Tags: android, service

I have an Activity and a Service and I want to call a method that located in the Activity from the service.

The method (`deleteItem`) uses Notification Service to cancel some notification, but because of it, I get the error:

`E/AndroidRuntime(13172): java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()`

**MainActivity:**

```
public boolean deleteItem(SQLiteDatabase db, long id) {
    if(db.delete(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, "`_id` = " + id, null) == 1) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Item #"+id + " was deleted successfully!");

            ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).cancel((int) id);

            return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

**Service:**

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    id = intent.getIntExtra("id", -1);
    MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
    main.deleteItem(db, id, false);

}
```

How can I solve the error?

Answer (score 0):

```
MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
```

Instantiating activities is the android framework's job. Please don't do this.

Call the method from the service itself. Why does it even need to be on the activity ?

Comment: Because I use it in the activity and the service and I want to save some code instead of write the same method in two places. So you suggest to write the same method in the service?

Comment: No, I'm all for reuse but this is called the wrong way. Write a DAO to handle the delete() call. You can always get the notification service from an application context or the activity's context. That is independent of the database operation.